# What would cause a cookie set with ColdFusion to expire at session close when never was specified?

Tags: coldfusion

I am setting a cookie with ColdFusion like `<cfcookie name="pass" value="1" expires="never">` but the cookie is expiring at session close. I have application.cfm specifying clientmanagement="yes" and setclientcookies="yes" and I am not redirecting with cflocation on the same page the cookie is set.  Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Hmmm.... do you only have this code existing in one place? Do you ever manipulate the "pass" cookie elswhere?

Comment: Just one place and it's not manipulated again. Just checked for its existance.

Comment: And your browser has local storage enabled yes? have you tried different browsers? (I assume you have - just noodling along with you).

Comment: Yep, cookies are enabled. The client reported having to log in repeatedly. I didn't notice it because I rarely close my browser. I thought it maybe an IE issue but seems to be any browser used.

Comment: You aren't showing us enough; there's a hidden tidbit we're not being told. Instead of using the example syntax above, copy/paste in here the *actual* CFCOOKIE call you're making, with *all* attributes as they exist in your problematic code.

Comment: As an aside, the problem that made it so that you could not do a cflocation on a page that sets a cookie has been fixed for over 10 years.

Comment: The code I showed is the actual code. No hidden tidbits.

Comment: Have you tried something other than "never"?  How about expires="10000", does that work?

Comment: Then, you have something else going on in your Application.cfm, unrelated to clientmanagement (the CLIENT scope) and setclientcookies (which cookifies CFID/CFTOKEN automatically)--neither of which affect your issue. Start posting your Application.cfm

Comment: Additionally, post your OS/Browser, and the code you are using to examine the cookie after you close/re-open your browser, which is presumably throwing an error because the cookie does not exist (or, alternately, the tool you are using to confirm the cookie does not exist).

Comment: Here's another slant to try: Assuming you're on windows, install fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and record your session with the minimum number of pages loads to re-create the problem. Now look at the request and response panels on the right. Use the Headers or Raw tabs to see what CF is sending to the browser and the browser is sending to the server. At some point the cookie will stop being sent and you want to see if the server is sending a set-cookie header to the client just before that. The other possibility is something in javascript clearing the cookie?